# Spacing between strings

Tags: c, printf

```
puts("***************** CURRENT TRANSACTIONS *****************");
puts("DATE\t\tDESCRIPTION\t\tAMOUNT");
for (int i = 0; i < blocks; i++)
{
    if (strcmp("DEPOSIT", description[i]) == 0 || strcmp("deposit", description[i]) == 0)
        printf("%s\t%s\t\t\t+%s\n", date[i], description[i], amount[i]);
    else
        printf("%s\t%s\t-%s\n", date[i], description[i], amount[i]);
}
```

}

I have made a program like the one above. It supposed to prints strings out according to an array. Everything works fine except that the output is not even. The data is supposed to be in a chart-like format where the beginning of each string begins in the same place as the beginning of the heading, but due to the length of certain strings, \t does not even this out. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this other than creating a bunch of if statements that check the length of the string?

Example:

```
DATE            DESCRIPTION            AMOUNT
BLAH BLAH       BLAH                   BLAH BLAH BLAH
BLAH            BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH    BLAH
BLAH BLAH BLAH  BLAH BLAH              BLAH BLAH
```

Comment: Just repeat print space (column width - content length) times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `printf` for this.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%-20s%-50s%-30s\n", "DATE", "DESCRIPTION", "AMOUNT");
    printf("%-20s%-50s%-30s\n", "BLAH BLAH", "BLAH", "BLAH BLAH BLAH");
    printf("%-20s%-50s%-30s\n", "BLAH", "BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH", "BLAH BLAH");
    printf("%-20s%-50s%-30s\n", "BLAH BLAH BLAH", "BLAH BLAH", "BLAH");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the sample output.

```
DATE                DESCRIPTION                                       AMOUNT                        
BLAH BLAH           BLAH                                              BLAH BLAH BLAH                
BLAH                BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH                               BLAH BLAH                     
BLAH BLAH BLAH      BLAH BLAH                                         BLAH
```